# How to render parentheses as part of url in gtk label?

Tags: html, c, gtk

I am using gtk in an application and I make use of the abilities of gtklabel text to be rendered automatically as a clickable url. This works well most of the time, however with a url which contains parentheses "(" and ")" this does not work. The versions I use are the ones available on debian (old)stable, i.e. debian 6 (2.20) and 7 (3.4.2).

For example, I am trying to display the following url:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=62.1891,+-141.5372+(Example+text+in+here+will+be+rendered+in+the+maps+label)&iwloc=A&hl=en
```

When I create a gtklabel with this text, for example:

```
text="<b><a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=62.1891,+-141.5372+(Example+text+in+here+will+be+rendered+in+the+maps+label)&iwloc=A&hl=en\" title=\"Map\">Click here for Map</a></b>\n"
```

Then it will display fine in the label as an underlined link in bold with the text **Click here for Map**

However when you click the link it will not show correctly and this error appears:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to show '(null)': Operation not supported
```

It looks like the parentheses mess up the rendering of the url by gtk.

Is there a way to escape the parentheses, or use a different character that works in the map url to create the label?

I have tried various methods of escaping it, however none were effective so far. Such as using %28 and %29 to replace the parentheses as well as backslashes as an escape character.

I am using the method described in https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkLabel.html and https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html under "Links" which allows automatic rendering of links:

> Links
>
> Since 2.18, GTK+ supports markup for clickable hyperlinks in addition
>   to regular Pango markup. The markup for links is borrowed from HTML,
>   using the a with href and title attributes. GTK+ renders links similar
>   to the way they appear in web browsers, with colored, underlined text.
>   The title attribute is displayed as a tooltip on the link. An example
>   looks like this:
>
> 1 gtk_label_set_markup (label, "Go to the http://www.gtk.org\" title=\"<i>Our&/i> website\">GTK+
>   website for more...");

I understand it is working in more recent releases of gtk (2.24 and 3.6), making sure to escape ampersands. But I was wondering if there is a work around for older gtk versions to avoid this problem?

Comment: Please *mention* the "various methods" you already tried, to avoid people suggesting and you saying "yeh I tried that already". Did you try the most common form of URL-escaping? `%28...%29`

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug - have you reported it at http://bugzilla.gnome.org?

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. I forgot where (probably somewhere on https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/) but I remember reading that the rendering engine is not perfect and may not render everything as expected. So I am looking for a work around.

Comment: Actually, even if it is not a bug but it's intended to be that way it's still a useful feature, therefore I submitted a bug https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720811

Comment: @ptomato: sounds a it light on clues to open a bug report on so little evidence. GTK+ bugtracker is filled with hundreds of unread bug reports, doesn't need one more if we're not sure it's a real bug.

Comment: Please specify the version of GTK you're using, and give us the code showing the way you manipulate the label to set that value and tell it to interpret it as markup. This works perfectly on GTK 3.6.4.

Comment: @liberforce Presumably when the OP goes to create a minimal example to attach to the bug, they'll find out if it's a real bug or not.

Comment: @ptomato: not everyone thinks about creating a minimal code example to reproduce the bug, before opening the bug. Thus it's better to insist on this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jku is right, the ampersand need to be escaped. He're an example using the very same string as you, and it works (tested on 3.6.4 and 2.24.17).

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
//  This one won't work, needs ampersand escaping
//  GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new ("<b><a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=62.1891,+-141.5372+(Example+text+in+here+will+be+rendered+in+the+maps+label)&iwloc=A&hl=en\" title=\"Map\">Click here for Map</a></b>\n");
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new ("<b><a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=62.1891,+-141.5372+(Example+text+in+here+will+be+rendered+in+the+maps+label)&amp;iwloc=A&amp;hl=en\" title=\"Map\">Click here for Map</a></b>\n");
    gtk_label_set_use_markup (GTK_LABEL (label), TRUE);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), label);
    gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET (window));
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

**Original answer:**

Have you tried to call gtk_show_uri with that link? You could then see if that's a problem with what handles URI's, or if it's the way your label is formatted/constructed.

Comment: Yes in a different part of the application a menu option can be chosen to browse the same link using gnome_url_show() which works fine. It's a problem with how the markup language in the label is rendered.

Comment: Thank you, I will try my code with gtk 2.24 and 3.6.4. My application has been on stable release for a couple of years it would be nice to have it work on distributions that use older gtk versions. That's why I was looking for a possible work around.

Comment: Could you please test my sample code on your GTK versions an tell me if the bug is there or not?

Comment: Yes your sample code is working ok on my system. I am trying to figure out why my code is not yet working ok. I use gtk_label_set_markup() instead of gtk_label_set_use_markup(), but I tried the latter which didn't work either. Still looking...

Comment: You may try to call `gtk_label_new (NULL)` and then `gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL(label), "<b>blah</b>")`. But you want more help, we need some code. Please try to have create  minimal example reproducing the problem. This may also help you find out why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Marking your answer as correct because it adds a working example thanks. I create an example and it worked correctly, which convinced me I still had an error in my own code after I fixed the "&amp;". I found the error (just a small typo) and now it.s working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should be escaping your ampersands with `&amp;`.

I'm pretty sure GTK prints out a runtime warning telling you this when you call `gtk_label_set_markup()`.

Here's the warning on GTK 3.6.4:

`Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to set text from markup due to error parsing markup: Error on line 1: Entity did not end with a semicolon; most likely you used an ampersand character without intending to start an entity - escape ampersand as &amp;`

Comment: I am not using gtk_label_set_markup() and in the example above I just added to the question it shows that ampersands don't need to be escaped.

Comment: It in no way shows that ampersands don't need to be escaped, there's a bug in the example provided in the documentation. Instead of `title=\"&lt;i&gt;Our&/i&gt; website\"`, it should be written `title=\"&lt;i&gt;Our&lt;/i&gt; website\"`

Comment: And BTW, if you don't use `gtk_label_set_markup`, what are you using ? `g_object_set` ? Please show us the code where you assign the text.

Comment: I just tried `gtk_label_set_markup` and escaped the ampersands, and it works. No GTK bug here.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I was mistaken, I am using gtk_label_set_markup() however it does not show a warning, which is consistent with what you said since I am using debian stable versions, both debian 6 (2.20) and 7 (3.4.2). Maybe a fix can be backported there? I guess there is no work around?

Comment: I forgot, escaping of ampersands is not fixing the problem on the gtk versions I use on debian 6 and 7. But it's of course still a helpful suggestion.

Comment: GNOME definitely isn't going to bother with backporting to ancient releases and I doubt Debian would do that either (stable is stable, with bugs and all). 
Still, it sounds weird that parenthesis would be a problem even with ancient versions... GMarkup is indeed very primitive but this does not look that difficult to parse. Have you double-checked that the issue really is parenthesis? That you have a test case (like liberforces) that doesn't work even with escaping, but works if you remove only the parenthesis?

Comment: See my comment, below, thanks for the help and both answers helped to identify the problems and in addition fix a small typo I had in my source.